# pipemapred waitoutputthreads subprocess failed with code 255

Tags: azure, hadoop, mapreduce, streaming, azure-hdinsight

I am running a simple Map/Reduce job on Azure HDInsight (Hadoop). The mapper fails with the following error (from the JobTracker log)...

```
2014-03-27 16:42:50,330 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress: Error from attempt_201403262112_0004_m_000000_0: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 255
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:576)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:135)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:365)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1233)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260)
```

I am connecting to the cluster using the Hadoop.Connect method...

```
// Connect to the HDInsight cluster
var hadoop = Hadoop.Connect(hadoopClusterUri,
                            hadoopUserName,
                            localHadoopUser,
                            hadoopPassword,
                            asvAccount,
                            asvKey,
                            asvContainer,
                            createContinerIfNotExist);
```

Since the job is started and logged I assume the connection is successful. As a simple test, I am emitting a tiny amount of data...

```
context.EmitKeyValue("This is a key", "This is a value");
```

Completely stumped,
Bill

**Update**
This MapReduce spawns two jobs. This first completes successfully and the second fails with the following exception...

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.StreamingException: The user type could not be loaded. DLL=MapReduce.exe, Type=PrescienceRx.MapReduce.BeneficiaryMapper ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;file:///c:\apps\temp\hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\admin\jobcache\job_201403262112_0006\attempt_201403262112_0006_m_000001_0\work\MapReduce.exe&apos; or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
at Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.MapperMain.Main()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

at Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.MapperMain.Main()
   at Microsoft.HdInsight.MapDriver.Program.Main(String[] args

Comment: It looks like you are running a streaming job, and the mapper is exiting with a code of 255 (or -1).  If you can share some details about what language your mapper is written in, we might be able to help further.

Comment: Hey Rick. Your assumptions are true, I have written a mapper and am running a streaming job. My cluster is deployed on Azure HDInsight and I have written the mapper in c# using the .Net SDK for Hadoop (Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce).

Comment: The first is the Templeton Controller job, and doesn't interact with your MapReduce code at all.  Can you confirm that you're building for .Net 4.0 or earlier?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly` is probably because of a mismatch between the loader's .Net version and your assembly.  Try setting it back to 4.0 and then in the NuGet Package Manager Window do `update-package -reinstall Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce` to make sure you have all of the correct versions.

Answer (score 0):

I set the target CPU to x64 in the solution's configuration manager and that resolved the issue.